# 2 IntelliSense: argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR"

Tags: c++, winapi

Stackflow Members   ---- i'm beginner in c++ WINAPI --- when i coding in my first WIN32  GUI, appeared some errors [OUTPUT]  --- Are there any recommended books to be advanced in C++ --- my codes:

```
#include <windows.h>
const char g_szClassName[] = ("myWindowClass");
 LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) { 
   switch(msg)    {    
   case WM_CLOSE:     
   DestroyWindow(hwnd);    
   break;     
   case WM_DESTROY:  
   PostQuitMessage(0);  
   break;     
   default:    
   return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);  
   }  
   return 0; 
   }
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,  
  LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {  
  WNDCLASSEX wc;   
  HWND hwnd;  
  MSG Msg;
    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style         = 0;  
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;  
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;  
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;  
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);   
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW); 
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);  
    wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;  
    wc.lpszClassName = (g_szClassName);  
    wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc))    {  
    MessageBox(NULL,
        L"Window Registration Failed!",
    L"Error!",     
    MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);  
    return 0;  
    }
    // Creating the Window   
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(    
    WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,   
    (g_szClassName),     
    L"The title of my window",      
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,      
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 240, 120,        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    if(hwnd == NULL)    {  
    MessageBox(NULL, 
        L"Window Creation Failed!",
        L"Error!",    
    MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);     
    return 0;  
    }
    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);  
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);
    // Step 3: The Message Loop    
    while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)    {     
    TranslateMessage(&Msg);       
    DispatchMessage(&Msg); 
    }  
    return Msg.wParam; 
    }
```

output :

```
    3   IntelliSense: argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR"  c:\Users\Youssef\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Win32Project2\Win32Project2\Win32Project2.cpp    46  2   Win32Project2
    2   IntelliSense: a value of type "const char *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "LPCWSTR"  c:\Users\Youssef\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Win32Project2\Win32Project2\Win32Project2.cpp    34  19  Win32Project2
Error   1   error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "stdafx.h"' to your source?   c:\users\youssef\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\win32project2\win32project2\win32project2.cpp    65  1   Win32Project2
```

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049481/problems-with-cfiledialog-instantiation/27049624#27049624  Basically, you are building an application that takes wide strings in the Windows functions, but the strings you created are not wide character strings.  See the link for more info.

Comment: You already know how to prefix `L` to string literals to turn them into Unicode strings, just do it consistently.

Comment: The other error says *"Did you forget to add '#include "stdafx.h"'* to your source?" , so include that in first line, or go to project properties -> C/C++ -> precompiled headers and change the file setting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compilation issue you're having has to do with string types and Windows programs.

Note that there are two character set "build types" for a Windows program.  The first is `MBCS` and the second is `Unicode`.  By default (assuming you're using Visual Studio), the build type is `Unicode`, meaning that the various Windows API functions will process wide strings, not `char` or `char`-based strings.

The easiest solution to your problem is to use `TCHAR` for character arrays and `_T()` macro for string literals meant to be sent and received from Windows API functions.  This will ensure your app will compile for Unicode, as well as MBCS (although MBCS programs are now considered obsolete in this day and age).

This line:

```
 wc.lpszClassName = (g_szClassName);
```

gives an issue, since you are compiling a Unicode application, and this member of `WNDCLASSEX` takes an `LPCTSTR` (a pointer to `TCHAR`), not a `const char *`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633577%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

So for this problem,

```
const char g_szClassName[] = ("myWindowClass");
```

The change should be:

```
#include <tchar.h> // in case it isn't included 
//...
TCHAR g_szClassName[] = _T("myWindowClass");
```

Comment: Note that the `_T()` macro belongs to the C runtime library, for use with the `_TCHAR` type.  The Win32 API, on the other hand, has its own `TCHAR` type and `TEXT()` macro.  Technically, `_TCHAR` and `TCHAR`, `_T()` and `TEXT()`, all map to the same data type and thus are interchangeable, but logically they belong to different APIs and should not be mixed.  Use the appropriate type/macro for each library call you make (in this case, the Win32 API), so `_T()` with `_TCHAR`, `TEXT()` with `TCHAR` - `TCHAR g_szClassName[] = TEXT("myWindowClass");`

Comment: And don't forget the `MessageBox()` and `CreateWindowEx()` calls in this code are also `TCHAR`-based, so use the `TEXT()` macro for those literals as well, eg: `MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Window Registration Failed!"), TEXT("Error!"), MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);`, otherwise use the `WCHAR` functions instead, eg: `MessageBoxW(NULL, L"Window Registration Failed!", L"Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);`